# Clonezilla SE issues

Tags: 12.04, dell, clonezilla

This is my first go-around with Clonezilla SE. I have it on it's own, private, network where the server is also serving DHCP to the machines that join the network.

Server: Dell Optiplex 790 (SFF)
OS: Ubuntu 12.04

I am having two issues:

1) We have two models of desktops in house... Dell Optiplex 790's (about 90%) and Optiplex 7010's (about 10%). When booting to NIC, both machines obtain IP's and recognize the DRBL server almost instantly... They boot into DRBL where they are presented with boot options (Ubuntu 12.04 | Clonezilla SE | Client OS | Memtest). When I hit to boot into Clonezilla, the 7010's wait a few seconds and then proceed to boot appropriately. The 790's, on the other hand, don't do anything for about 5 or 6 minutes before, finally, going into Clonezilla. After they get in, they image just fine. I read about the kernel issues, but I just don't really know what to look for there... Also, the problem PC's are the same model as the server...

2) We want to use Multi-casting for imaging as we are going to have to image about 200 machines in the next few months. When I connect one machine to image, it finishes in about 6 minutes. When two machines connect, it goes up to about 17.5 minutes each. We are using, at this point, a small 5-port Netgear (gigabit) switch.

Any help people can provide in these areas would be GREATLY appreciated.

Thank you,
Wes Crockett